# Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I am trying to build  A CONVERSATIONAL BOT. when I am trying to pass the response with next , its not getting reflected din the next functions .

```
bot.dialog('Barcode',
    (session, args, next) => {
        var intent = args.intent;
        var id = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Report.Id');
          if (id) {
            next({ response: id.entity });

        } else {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Please enter your id');
        }
      session.endDialog();
    }  ,
      (session,results) => {

          var id = results.response;
           session.send(id.toString());  -- i want the value to be passed here 
      }
).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Barcode'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement a workflow in a dialog, you can set `IDialogWaterfallStep|IDialogWaterfallStep[]` in the second parameter in `dialog()` function.

In your code, you forget to cover `[]` outside the steps.

Try:

```
bot.dialog('Barcode',[
    (session, args, next) => {
        var intent = args.intent;
        var id = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Report.Id');
          if (id) {
            next({ response: id.entity });

        } else {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Please enter your id');
        }
      session.endDialog();
    }  ,
      (session,results) => {

          var id = results.response;
           session.send(id.toString());  -- i want the value to be passed here 
      }]
).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Barcode'
})
```